# Add number, inside the table of contents, to the Index printed with \printindex from imakeidx

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing, imakeidx

I have almost done with my document, but the problem is that when I print my Index, the table of contents is not showing me the corresponding number (I want to make it as a chapter). So, I used
`\makeindex[columns=3, title=Indice Analitico, intoc, options= -s example_style.ist]` at the beginning, and then `\printindex`, but the result inside the toc is not the expected one. Here there is a small example of my issue:

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[columns=3, title=Index, intoc, 
           options= -s example_style.ist]
 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \chapter{First Chapter}
 This is the first \index{first} chapter
 \printindex
 \chapter{Third Chapter}
 \end{document}
```

So the result in the table of contents is this:
[image: No number 2 before Index]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that .

Comment: Thank you, I've added it and I hope it's a good example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** Thanks for the example!

<strike>You didn't provide a compilable example, but</strike> the case is covered in the package [documentation](https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/macros/latex/contrib/imakeidx/imakeidx.pdf).

Here's an answer assuming that you are using the `book` class. Meaning that you want the TOC to include a numbered `\chapter`-level index.

The same holds for the `article` class, mutatis mutandis (you want the index to be on the `\section` level).

Disable the option `intoc` of `\makeindex` and use instead the option `level` of `\indexsetup`.
From p. 5 of the documentation:

> *level* which takes as value a sectioning command such as `\chapter` or `\chapter*`. Actually any command with an argument will do and will receive the index title as its argument. **The default is `\chapter*` or, if the class doesn’t provide chapters, `\section*`.** If you specify [level] so as to override the default `\chapter*`, the index title goes directly to the table of contents; in this case do not specify the `intoc` option.

(emphasis mine.) The default value is the **starred** version of either `\chapter` or `\section`, which produces an unnumbered chapter/section. Change this to the **unstarred** version.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex[columns=3, 
title=Indice Analitico, 
%intoc,             % disable option "intoc"
]

\indexsetup{        % if unspecified, "level" defaults to \chapter* or \section*
level=\chapter      % numbered chapter in book class
%level=\section     % numbered section in article class
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Capitolo Primo}

\index{an item}
\index{another item}

\printindex

\chapter{Capitolo Secondo}

\end{document}
```

And here's the new TOC.

[image: TOC with numbered index]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @LuigiGG You're welcome! And now you've provided basically the same example I came up with :)